# The status bar of Ubuntu is abnormal after reinstalling gnome according to ChatGPT prompt

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons, gnome-panel

The command ChatGPT gave me is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon gnome-control-center gnome-terminal nautilus gnome-tweak-tool

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon gnome-control-center gnome-terminal nautilus gnome-tweak-tool
```

After doing this, the running clash icon and indicator-sysmonitor that should have appeared in the lower right corner of the status bar disappeared.

For example: On the right side of the status bar here, there should be a small golden icon when the clash is running, but now there is the system default time, wifi and sound, etc.
[image]

Use nohup indicator-sysmonitor & start indicator-sysmonitor. There should be real-time network speed, GPU, CPU usage and other information on the right side of the status bar. However, after starting, the right side of my ubuntu on the right side remains unchanged.
[image]

My previous status bar was normal. Software that should be running in the background, such as clash, QQ, indicator-sysmonitor,Microsoft input method application, etc., after closing the running window that will be displayed on the left side of the status bar, their small icons will still be there. On the right side of the status bar, I can view the application status at any time

My guess is that when I use apt remov uninstalling the applications, I accidentally deleted and uninstalled other related applications in the system, but I don’t know what they were.

Comment: Basic starting point would be what OS/release you're using, I'd not have used those packages for a Ubuntu Desktop system, but the instructions you used can work for non-Ubuntu's equally well (*where I'd have consider your OS & release; as packages are built for specific releases!*)  What was removed will be consequence of your prior commands, which if you don't remember, will be recorded in your apt logs; `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: It would be good to indicate what you mean by the "running clash icon". No idea what that means. Also, there is little in the bottom right corner, except the Home folder icon in a default installation. Note that people reading your question cannot know whether you perhaps customized the system.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I found that I uninstalled a plug-in for gnome that caused this situation. Its name is “ubuntu appindicators” and after reinstalling it everything showed up fine.